# Bulk convert Doc to Docx using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I have legacy folder with mix of all kinds of files numbering around 55,000 over the network drive. I have to convert all doc format to .docx format file, there are around 40,000 files in doc format. So far, I have tried following approach

1) **MS Office Migration Planning Manager and MS Office Compatibility Pack** as suggested at these two [links1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/09/18/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx/)  and [Link2](https://superuser.com/questions/32033/batch-convert-doc-to-docx-and-equivilent-for-other-office-formats/34398) .
 Both of theses approach are same. In this case each file Conversion takes almost 25 seconds because it also processes other format file like .xls in addition to conversion. That means whole conversion will take 4-5 days even if I use multiple machines with distributed folders.

2) **Third Party Tools like ASPOS and NPOI**: NPOI doesn't have docx support yet. I am using trial version of ASPOS, Although it takes two seconds/ file but it truncates all pages but first and adds its copyright message at header. Since conversion of folder is only one time effort so buying a licensed version is not feasible.

3) **MS office interop library or Word 14.0 Object Library**: it takes more than 30 seconds / file over network. So not considering it at all.

My conversion **target is less than 5 seconds/file**. Because we'll not get more that one day to access the secured n/w drive.

Comment: How large are the files? Interop would be the way to go IMHO. I am not sure why it's taking so long.

Comment: On average file size is 25kb. since conversion is over network drive total time is so high. Even conversion at local drive through Interop is taking around 8-10 seconds.

Comment: It doesn't seem right. It shouldn't take that long, even with a network drive.  Are you using separate threads by the way? That would speed things up. Just make sure you don't choke the drive though.

Comment: we didn't  used multithreaded approach for interop.  Even through MS office migration manager time per file conversion is 8-10 seconds, which is better option than interop.  Now we  are working on our own customized  multithread tool which will be deployed over multiple machine  and targeting different set of folders to reduce overall conversion time. Through this approach we are expecting 3 seconds/file and total conversion to complete within 8 hours.